# how to use scrollview in cocos2d (iphone)?

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

how to use a scrollview in cocos2d...

Comment: First result in google: http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/21/cocos2d-and-uiscrollview/. That looks like exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I've looked for this sort of thing as well, almost all implementations of a "ScrollView" are all Paged and don't allow for smooth continuous scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing scrollable menu and gallery right now and started with CCScrollLayer but it doesn't work as I want it to work and decided to use UIScrollView. It's really simple and does what it should